# Mi archivo PHP no me deja iniciar sesión

Tags: php, mysql

PHP

**Index:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gamer Experience</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/AtariJoy.png">
</head>
<header>
    <center>
        <h1 class="title">Gamer Experience</h1>
    </center>
</header>
<body class="indexbody">
    <center>
    <div class="divin">
        <form method="Post" action="conexion.php">
                <h2 class="login">Login</h2>
                <label class="userl">User: <input type="text" name="user" class="userin" maxlength="8"></label><br>
                <label class="passl">Password: <input type="password" name="pass" class="passin" maxlength="8"></label><br>
                <button class="btnIng" onclick="window.location.href='pagina_principal.php'">Ingresar</button><br>
                <a class="linkS" href="registro_usuario.php">Sign Up</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Conexión:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["nomUsu"];
$pass = $_POST["conUsu"];

if (isset($name)) {
    $conex = mysqli_connect("localhost","ventasWeb", "root", "") or die ("No se realizo la conexión");

    mysqli_select_db($conex,"ventasWeb") or die ("Error en la conexión a la base de datos");
}else{
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

**Base de Datos MySQL:**

```
create database ventasWeb;

use ventasWeb;

create table usuario(
    idUsu int auto_increment primary key,
    nomUsu varchar (8),
    conUsu varchar(8)
);

create table producto(
    idProd int auto_increment primary key,
    nomProd varchar (50),
    preProd int,
    stock int
);

insert into usuario values (null,'nicolas','nico123');

select * from usuario;
```

El problema pasa cuando le doy clic al **botón ingresar**, no me manda a la página principal sino que me redirecciona al index.

Comment: esa redirección es por tu **header("location:index.php");** tienes que cambiarla, por ejemplo **header("location:paginaPrincipal.php");** tienes que indicarle cual es tu página principal

Comment: Prueba `$name = $_POST["user"]; $pass = $_POST["pass"];`

Comment: Por un lado tienes que coger el name del input, como te comentan arriba, por otro lado, tienes un button con un click, cosa que no te hará el form = action, necesitas un submit.

Comment: el otro error es el te dijo @DavidSilva, los name de tus input tienen que ser los mismos de tus variables post

Comment: Además de todo lo que te han dicho, en realidad no estas comprobando nada en la consulta de la ta la de usuarios, por ende, solo estas comprobando de que se envia o no el campo nombre del formulario.

Comment: El dato que estás buscando en el post `nomUsu` realmente no existe (a no ser que hayas serializado o mandado los datos de otra forma incoherente). Los formulario se serializan usando como clave la etiqueta `name` de los elementos y en tu formulario el input del usuario no se llama `nomUsu` sino `user`, por tanto debes hacer lo que te dice David Silva. @EduBw los formularios se pueden enviar también con botones, incluso si no son del tipo `submit`, si el código Javascript escucha los clicks del botón y desde ahí se envía el formulario.

Comment: No viene con el tema, pero te aconsejo que no guardes la contraseña en texto plano en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Modifica tu código a:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gamer Experience</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/AtariJoy.png">
</head>
<header>
    <center>
        <h1 class="title">Gamer Experience</h1>
    </center>
</header>
<body class="indexbody">
    <center>
    <div class="divin">
        <form method="Post" action="iniciarsesion.php">
                <h2 class="login">Login</h2>
                <label class="userl">User: <input type="text" name="nomUsu" class="userin" maxlength="8"></label><br>
                <label class="passl">Password: <input type="password" name="conUsu" class="passin" maxlength="8"></label><br>
                <button type="submit" class="btnIng">Ingresar</button><br>
                <a class="linkS" href="registro_usuario.php">Sign Up</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Por otro lado, tu consulta esta mal, en ningún momento creas una session...
Crea un archivo llamado "conexion.php" y le pones este código:

```
<?php
//servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos
    $conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","ventasweb"); 

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }

?>
```

Crea el archivo "iniciarsesion.php" y le pones:

```
<?php
session_start();

$nombre = $_POST['nomUsu'];
$password = $_POST['conUsu'];

require_once 'conexion.php';
// se asume conexion en $conn incluido desde conexion.php, ejemlo:
// $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ventasweb");

// añadiría un limit 1 a la consulta pues solo esperamos un registro
$consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nomUsu = '$nombre' AND conUsu = '$password'");  

// esto válida si la consulta se ejecuto correctamente o no
// pero en ningún caso válida si devolvió algún registro
if(!$consulta){ 
    // echo "Usuario no existe " . $nombre . " " . $password. " o hubo un error " . 
    echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
    // si la consulta falla es bueno evitar que el código se siga ejecutando
    exit;
} 
// este else sobra
//else { 
    //print "Bienvenido"; 
//} 

// validemos pues si se obtuvieron resultados 
// Obtenemos los resultados con mysqli_fetch_assoc
// si no hay resultados devolverá NULL que al convertir a boleano para ser evaluado en el if será FALSE
if($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
    // el usuario y la pwd son correctas
} else {
    // Usuario incorrecto o no existe
}


?>
```

Comment: Ojo, en `$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","",ventasweb"); ` faltan unas comillas

Comment: Gracias, ya lo arregle :)